# Codenameone: Read device information using native code

Tags: mobile, codenameone

I have to read device information that's why I have added Android code in codename one under native/Android code. My code is

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

In this code getting problem to implement `getSystemService` method.
I have included android.jar library still getting the problem.

So can you tell me which library required and what import statement should require for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the android jar as that is builtin. I'm guessing you didn't import the package correctly but without an error message it's hard to guess.

Comment: Then which libray to include and which import statement to used

Comment: right now getting error "nativeapp/MyNativeImpl.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
     TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable Context
  location: class MyNativeImpl

Comment: Don't include any library, they are built in. You can get the context from AndroidNativeUtil. See some of our native demos such as Dr. Sbaitso.

Comment: No there is nothing new about this